# Using bot.register_next_step_handler in telegram bot I get TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, typeerror, telegram-bot, nonetype, py-telegram-bot-api

The idea is to get telegram bot that receives from user some data, handles it, displays the result and then repeats the whole cycle not waiting a command from user. Here is the code:

```
from telebot import TeleBot

TOKEN = ""

bot = TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def regata(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Enter tmfs separated with space: ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, bla)


def bla(message):
    data_from_tg = message.text.split()
    tmf_1 = data_from_tg[0]
    tmf_2 = data_from_tg[1]
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Result: {tmf_1 + tmf_2}')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, regata(message))


bot.polling()
```

So the bot is working, but unfortunately after the second result is sent to user it fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\bot\testbot.py", line 21, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 664, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 726, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 686, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 135, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 87, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Do I need to use some another pytelegrambotapi methods to implement the idea? Why does it work two times, but fails in the end?
Thank you in advance for any ideas.

Comment: I suggest to revoke your token, because it is still visible in question history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def regata(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Enter tmfs separated with space: ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, bla)


def bla(message):
    data_from_tg = message.text.split()
    tmf_1 = data_from_tg[0]
    tmf_2 = data_from_tg[1]
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Result: {tmf_1 + tmf_2}')
    regata(message)


bot.polling()
```

Anyway, I suggest to not use register_next_step_handler. You can easily do the same in this way:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def regata(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Enter tmfs separated with space: ')

@bot.message_handler():
def bla(message):
    data_from_tg = message.text.split()
    tmf_1 = data_from_tg[0]
    tmf_2 = data_from_tg[1]
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Result: {tmf_1 + tmf_2}')
    regata(message)

bot.polling()
```